# Create a pod from registry running on the same cluster

Tags: kubernetes, harbor

I am running Harbor Registry on my cluster and I have no problem pushing and pulling the images from outside of the cluster.

Now I'd like to be able to create a pod from that registry.
Something like this:

```
.
kubectl run -i --tty --rm debug --image=harbor.harbor.svc.cluster.local/test/alpine:latest --restart=Never -- sh

.
```

Is this possible?

**Update**

If I try to access the registry by its service name `harbor.harbor.svc.cluster.local` it doesn't work because the host name is not found.

How can I reference my image?

Answer (score 1):

As @Rajesh mentioned in comment, you need to create [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) type service if you are on same subnet with your nodes or if you are using some cloud for your cluster such as AWS, GKE, also you can create [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) type service and access through External Loadbalancer to your registry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. There is also concept of local registry which is part of cluster and you can pull images from their. Even OpenShift come with local registry.

Comment: then how can I reference my local registry? Node should know the host name to pull the images. Which hostname I can use?

Comment: you should expose local registry with kubernetes service. So you will get common NodePort which is same on every node of cluster. You can use any node IP and NodePort to access your registry.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not a single setup invocation as the one you envisage. There are a set of steps (read as prerequisites) you must follow to get this sorted:

1. Setup local registry on the node
2. Setup of docker certificates - required for secure access to the local registry from your pod
3. Setup of k8s secret which will be part of your deployment - required to access your local registry on the node
4. Lastly, the deployment itself